# How to pass cost related parameters into customised scoring function in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, scoring

I am writing a code to evaluate ML model performance on Python using my **own scoring function**. I need to improve model performance by tuning hyperparameters according to my own scoring metric (which includes cost and revenue information apart from y_true and y_pred)

desired score metric looks some what like this:

```
 #true positives * (revenue) + #true negatives*(revenue) + #false positives *(cost) + #false negatives *(-revenue)
```

However, the examples of make_scorer and custom_scoring_function I found in scikit-learn of python only
show how to build a custom function with y_true and y_pred values.

I wish to pass a dataframe with y_true, y_pred, cost, revenue information into the custom scoring function.

Following is a basic draft of the cost function i want to implement

```
def my_custom_loss_func(dataframe):
for i,r dataframe.iterrows():
    if treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    elif treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    elif treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    elif treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    elif treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    elif treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    elif treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    elif treatment[i] =1 & y_true[i] = 1 & y_pred[i]=1:n_jobs=-1
        dataframe['rev']=RE78[i]-TreatmentCost[i]
    return(sum(dataframe['rev']))
```

This is what I found on scikit learn:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def my_custom_loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
...     diff = np.abs(y_true - y_pred).max()
...     return np.log1p(diff)
...
>>> # score will negate the return value of my_custom_loss_func,
>>> # which will be np.log(2), 0.693, given the values for X
>>> # and y defined below.
>>> score = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False)
>>> X = [[1], [1]]
>>> y = [0, 1]
>>> from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
>>> clf = DummyClassifier(strategy='most_frequent', random_state=0)
>>> clf = clf.fit(X, y)
>>> my_custom_loss_func(clf.predict(X), y)
0.69...
>>> score(clf, X, y)
-0.69...
```

my_custom_loss_func takes only y_true and y_pred in this scikit example.
Is there anyway to use this framework from scikit learn and implement my desired scoring function?